# Google Cloud Instance Groups - There is no backend service attached to the instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am getting an error on an instance group after updating the autoscaler min and max values.

This is running from Google Cloud Functions

```
var url = `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${projectId}/regions/${groupRegion}/autoscalers/`;

{
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      "name": "${groupName}",
       "target": `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${projectId}/regions/${groupRegion}/instanceGroupManagers/${groupName}`,
       "autoscalingPolicy": {
          "minNumReplicas": `${groupSizeMin}`,
          "maxNumReplicas": `${groupSizeMax}`,
          "loadBalancingUtilization": {
             "utilizationTarget": 0.8
           },
          "coolDownPeriodSec": 90
        }
    }
  }
```

The above is successful in setting the min and max values, however an error comes up on the Instance Group.

[This is the status that comes up on the instance group page on Google Cloud Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0uoS.png)

"**There is no backend service attached to the instance group**"

If I go into cloud console and remove the Auto Scaling by setting it to "Off", Save, and then turn it back on in the console, then the error is not there.

What am I missing during this update?

Comment: If you were to perform the same task manually using the GCP Console ... at the bottom of the page is an "equivalent REST" dialog that can be opened.  Does it compare well to the REST API you are sending?

Comment: @Kolban there is not an equivalent rest link at the bottom of the instance group edit page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [autoscalers documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/autoscalers), the property autoscalingPolicy.loadBalancingUtilization.utilizationTarget is only for setting an HTTP(S) load balancer.

If this is not the case, you should remove it from your query and the error will disappear.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, thank you, this worked as I needed it to.